# WP WOOCOMMERCE Вывод категорий

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

как можно вывести категорию товаров например на главную страницу, думал использовать rpwe плагин, но он выводит посты...
Я бы хотел вывести категории как топ категории в магазине, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Категория продукта - это "таксономия пользователя" product_cat используемая продуктами WooCommerce.

Вам нужно использовать get_terms() с правильной таксономией, вот так:

```
$categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );
```

Ну а вывести можете это и в index.php либо в шаблоне страниц либо где хотите.
Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос.